# How to replace values of a column when values of all columns except two match in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that look like this:

```
       iv_1  iv_2  iv_3  iv_4  iv_5  col2rplc  idenifier
0       0      0     0     0     0      a          1
333     0      0     0     0     0      b          0
      ......
222     1      2     3     4     5      aa         1
324     1      2     3     4     5      cc         0
      ......
1234    1      0     0     0     1      a          1
1235    0      2     0     4     0      a          1
1236    0      0     3     0     0      a          1
1237    0      0     1     0     0      b          o
1238    0      2     0     2     0      b          o
1239    3      0     0     0     3      b          o
```

This is two pandas dataframes concatenated. And identifier column identifies which set a particular row is from, set_1 or set_0. I would like to replace values of the column `col2rplc` in all the rows that have same values for all the columns of a set_0 with that of set_1. So, in the above example, for the first two rows, I would like b to be replaced with a; and i would like cc to be replaced with aa; while all the remaining rows of column `col2rplc`, where I don't have same values in rows, stay intact.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `duplicated` to identify duplicates rows then `mask` and `ffill`:

```
# sort the data accodringly
df = df.sort_values(['iv_1','iv_2','iv_3','iv_4','iv_5', 'idenifier'],
                    ascending=False)

mask = df.duplicated(df.columns[:5])
df['col2rplc'] = df['col2rplc'].mask(mask).ffill()
```

Output (notice you have an extra duplicate in the last few rows that you didn't mention in your question):

```
      iv_1  iv_2  iv_3  iv_4  iv_5 col2rplc  idenifier
0        0     0     0     0     0        a          1
222      1     2     3     4     5       aa          1
324      1     2     3     4     5       aa          0
333      0     0     0     0     0        a          0
1234     1     0     0     0     1        a          1
1235     0     2     0     2     0        a          1
1236     0     0     3     0     0        a          1
1237     0     0     1     0     0        b          0
1238     0     2     0     2     0        a          0
1239     3     0     0     0     3        b          0
```

Comment: The data I have shown here is created specifically for this question. It wasn't actually supposed to be a duplicate. i will edit it.

Comment: My code would still work, it just helps you detect the error that wasn't there. For your updated data, it should give what you listed there.

Comment: I have two doubts. 1. what will make sure that, for example, in first two rows of my example, `a` will be replaced by `b`, not the other way. 2. What would happen, if i have more than one exactly similar rows in set_1(that is when `idenifier` == 1), with only difference in value of column `col2rplc`(this is actually the case with my data).

Comment: 1. because `sort_values`, so rows with `idenifier 1` is always on top. 2. they all get replaced by the first value.

Comment: Huge Thanks for your time.